# How to fix the width of the table?

Tags: tables, longtable, column-width, adjustwidth

I want to control the width of my table, but the width is so long.
Could I get some ideas to fix this problem?

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{The examples of DTW distance for the Weizmann datasets.}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc} 
\toprule
two sequences & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}boxing\\vs boxing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}walking\\vs boxing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}running\\vs boxing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}jogging\\vs boxing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}handwaving\\vs boxing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}handclapping\\vs boxing\end{tabular}  \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){1-7}
DTW distance  & 0.5796                                                    & 1.7782                                                     & 0.8616                                                     & 1.1747                                                     & 1.3516                                                        & 0.969                                                            \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You seem to be in two-column mode?

Comment: Tabular* could be helpful.

Comment: Easiest way: Flip the table using two columns and seven rows instead of seven columns and two rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can save horizontal space by either leaving out redundant information ("vs boxing") which shouldn't be in a table anyways, or by changing the table layout from a 2x7 to a 7x2 grid. The following code shows both solutions.

The first fits in a one column document, but will still be too wide in a two column document.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption[The examples of DTW distance for the Weizmann datasets.]
    {The examples of DTW distance for the Weizmann datasets. Activities shown vs
    boxing.}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccc} 
    \toprule
    activity     & boxing & walking & running & jogging & waving & clapping \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-7}
    DTW distance & 0.5796 & 1.7782  & 0.8616  & 1.1747  & 1.3516 & 0.969    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{The examples of DTW distance for the Weizmann datasets.}
  \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=1.4]}
    \toprule
    activity vs boxing & {DTW distance} \\
    \midrule
    boxing             & 0.5796 \\
    walking            & 1.7782 \\
    running            & 0.8616 \\
    jogging            & 1.1747 \\
    waving             & 1.3516 \\
    clapping           & 0.969  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Results in a one-column document:

[image]

Results in a two-column document:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with the answer of Skillmon (+1) but do not answer specifically to "how to fix the width", that is, [how to force a table into the text width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10535/5001).

At this respect you have three possible approaches:  the `tabular*` environment or the packages `tabularx` or `tabulary`. In the tree cases  you must fix the width of the whole table to `\linewidth`:

```
\begin{tabular?}{\linewidth}{<type pf columns}}
```

Where `?` is `*`,`x` or `y` and the type of columns depend on type of environment. Since
the [difference between tabular* and tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341205/what-is-the-difference-between-tabular-tabular-and-tabularx-environments) is covered elsewhere, with `tabulary` could be:

```
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}LCCCCCC@{}}
....
\end{tabulary}
```

Of course, the result will be still horrendous,  because you cannot fit well 7 columns in about 8 cm (assuming a standard column) with so much text, so your options are:

1. Reduce the font. Maybe acceptable in other cases, but in your case will only fit (more or less) with `\tiny,` and even then the header will need 3 or 4 lines (far from the elegance, imho).
2. Take the two columns for the table, using  `table*`, or when the behavior of starred floats is a problem, using  `strip` of the `midfloat` package ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551123/placing-three-figure-environment-side-by-side-on-top-of-a-two-column-document)). Then the result is not too bad:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,array,xcolor,booktabs,tabulary}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering % \tiny for table 
\caption{The examples of DTW distance for the Weizmann datasets.}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}LCCCCCC@{}} 
\toprule
Two sequences & 
Boxing vs boxing & 
Walking vs boxing &
Running vs boxing & 
Jogging vs boxing & 
Handwaving vs boxing & 
Handclapping vs boxing\\\cmidrule{1-7}
DTW distance & 
0.5796 & 
1.7782 & 
0.8616 & 
1.1747 & 
1.3516 & 
0.969\\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

However, be able to fit in some way a table should never avoid ask yourself about the  design. For instance, beside the redundant headers, really you need four decimals?