# How to divide bibliography with figure and balance the text?

Tags: bibliographies

I want to place two figure to the top of the columns and balance text. However, I cannot place second figure to the top of the right column with \balance command since it can't divide reference. My attempts are given below with results. Notice the **%** in \balanced command.

```
\section{Conclusion}
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./images/fig5.png}
    \caption{Lorem Ipsum 5}
    \label{ab}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eleifend gravida lacus quis elementum. Vestibulum at erat non ipsum pretium rutrum. Aenean sodales massa non metus sollicitudin, sed rutrum dui sollicitudin. Vestibulum mollis enim at risus vulputate, at ornare nisi ornare. In vulputate, sem molestie luctus dignissim, magna metus ullamcorper sem, non mollis enim tellus ac lectus. Ut sollicitudin nulla odio, vel porta nunc viverra id. Integer posuere accumsan tortor at ultrices. Nulla facilisi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi hendrerit lorem sapien, nec iaculis turpis luctus venenatis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse congue posuere efficitur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eleifend gravida lacus quis elementum. Vestibulum at erat non ipsum pretium rutrum. Aenean sodales massa non metus sollicitudin, sed rutrum dui sollicitudin. Vestibulum mollis enim at risus vulputate, at ornare nisi ornare. In vulputate, sem molestie luctus dignissim, magna metus ullamcorper sem, non mollis enim tellus ac lectus.

%\balance
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./images/fig6.png}
    \caption{Lorem Ipsum 6}
    \label{abc}
\end{figure}
\balance

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my second attempt, I just remove **%** in first *\balance* command and add **%** to second *\balance* command. An the result is:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to divide bibliography so that I can place my figure to the top right corner. Can you help?

Comment: your code can not be tested but try to put both figures in one figure environment side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) stated, I implement successfully by using both figures in one figure environment. For future readers, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551126/296569) might help. I have solved my problem by adding the code below after the conclusion section:

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./images/fig5.png}
  \caption{First}
  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./images/fig6.png}
  \caption{Second}
  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).